# How to use Undo functionality in Nano?

Tags: command-line, nano

I use the commmand line text editor **nano**. How do I **undo** an action while editing text?

For example:
I typed some text and then changed my mind. Now I want to return to previous state. How?

Comment: You may want to consider changing the accepted answer here, as there is a newer, more accurate one.

Answer (score 243, accepted):

Starting with nano [version 2.3.5](http://www.nano-editor.org/dist/v2.3/ChangeLog) in July 2014, undo/redo became standard:

- <kbd>Alt-U</kbd> or <kbd>Option-U</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>U</kbd> - undo
- <kbd>Alt-E</kbd> or <kbd>Option-E</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> - redo

It's in the help:

[image]

And if you stretch the screen wider than about 1400 pixels, there's a hint at bottom right:

[image]

If these keys don't work, check `nano --version`.

- nano versions [2.1.10 - 2.3.4](https://www.nano-editor.org/dist/v2.7/ChangeLog) should use the command line option `-u` ([thanks](https://askubuntu.com/a/332962/215820) @sil). Tip:  add `alias nano="nano -u"` to your .bashrc (thanks @Benia). The implementation of undo during this period appears to have been buggy or incomplete.
- nano versions [2.1.3 - 2.1.9](https://www.nano-editor.org/dist/v2.7/ChangeLog) had some kind of undo feature. The `-u` option was not necessary.

`M` stands for [meta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_key).

Comment: Clicking alt+u doesn't work for me to undo.

Comment: @Benia try using Esc key instead of Alt. Let me know if that helps

Comment: Hi! Sadly it doesn't :\, Nano prints "Unkown command" also for ESC-U.

Comment: If you have an alternative or any idea what to check please publish in an answer and I will gladly give the bounty.

Comment: @Benia Version check ... `nano --version`

Comment: Indeed Nano is 2.2.6 and hence the prob. When I do sudo apt-get update and then sudo apt-get upgrade, it isn't change to Nano 3.x.x so I need to find a way to either update Nano individually or to upgrade the whole sys from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.0...

Comment: @Benia have you tried Sil's tip of running with the `-u` option? I seem to recall difficulties updating nano as well. Having a vague sense some security gnome somewhere has decided we don't need to.

Comment: Yes: Ben@DESKTOP-NJKJAQR:/mnt/c/Users/Ben$ Nano -u
No command 'Nano' found, did you mean:
 Command 'nano' from package 'nano' (main)

Comment: Right @Benia no capital N. `nano -u somefile.txt`

Comment: Oh sorry. Anyway, Nano works that way regularly 2.2.6

Comment: It doesn't change*

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46346/discussion-between-bobstein-visibone-and-benia).

Comment: Mac Users: Terminal > Preferences > Settings > Keyboard > ‘Use option as meta key’ @JohnDoea

Comment: I came here to know what does that `M` stand for

Comment: Alt + u works fine for me on ubuntu 16

Comment: I've noticed you need to do a `capital U` in some shells. This worked for me in GCP console. So, `Alt Shift u`.

Comment: Esc + u worked for me in RHEL 8

Comment: Thanks @Zolbayar, I found Esc-U seems to work everywhere Alt-U does. So I added it to the answer.

Comment: But I wonder why it's shown as `M-U` or `M-E` on nano. What's that `M`?

Comment: @Zolbayar also added to answer: M stands for [meta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_key).

Comment: Esc + U works fine on Mac OS 14 (Sonoma).

Answer (score 39):

Nano's undo code is experimental. As you'll see from the nano manual (type "`man nano`" in a Terminal to read that), you'll need to start nano with the `-u` option (so "`nano -u somefile.txt`"), and then you can use Alt-U to undo.

Comment: Thanks. There is also redo functionality and the shortcut for that is Alt+E.

Comment: You can edit /etc/nanorc to set it permanently (uncomment set undo). Note that under Mac you need to use esc|then|u to undo.

Answer (score 8):

You can also add the line

```
set undo
```

in the .nanorc file. This enables the experimental undo feature on startup in versions below 2.4, such as 2.2.6 which seems to be the standard installation on many Linux distros.