# How to enable undo in nano?

Tags: nano

How can I enable Undo in nano?
I am using a ssh connection with a server. I can not update the version of nano that is installed on the server. Is there anyway to use GNU nano 2.3.1 to have Undo function?

Comment: I managed to find out the solution. I hope this helps.
Use this command:
nano -u
Then use Alt+U for undo and Alt+E for redo.

Comment: This problem is just for the cases with nano 2.3.1.

Comment: This problem have been solved in newer version.

Comment: See [https://askubuntu.com/questions/332961/how-to-use-undo-functionality-in-nano#672091](https://askubuntu.com/questions/332961#672091).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Undo functionality in Nano?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/332961/how-to-use-undo-functionality-in-nano)

Comment: Yes actually it does. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Alt-U` to undo,

`Alt-E` to redo,

---

More hotkeys:

`Ctrl-K` to cut,

`Ctrl-U` to paste,

`Ctrl-Z` to send to background (`fg` to bring back)

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: Don't forget Alt+6 to copy.